# ArcPAD 10 backup shp files?

Tags: arcpad

Is there an automatic backup script for ArcPAD 10 when you are out in the field?

Answer (score 1):

No but it wouldn't take much to build a script. What do you need it to do? Copy at the end of a session? Zip the files up into different day names?

Some starting tips:

- If you leave ArcPad open while copying, make you sure you either turn off editing or pack the shapefile first before doing anything
- Use the File Copy Method to create a new file somewhere else.
- Use the Archive object to store copies in ZIP files

let us know how you go. If you need more assistance, just let me know.

Cheers,

Gareth